# Issue with XAML layout

Tags: xaml

I've got the following XAML:-

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="400">  
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading" />

   <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}" 
           Margin="0,12,0,12" />

   <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

This simply displays a heading, a listbox, and a button immediately below the listbox. As the number of items in the listbox grows, the button gets pushed down, however the listbox will keep growing and eventually disappear off the bottom of the window, taking the button with it.

Instead, I would like the listbox to grow until the button hits the bottom of the window. At this point the listbox shouldn't grow any further, and instead display scrollbars to scroll the list. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I've just come up with the following, which seems to do the trick. Not sure if there is a more elegant solution though?

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="400">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions >
     <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading" />

   <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Button" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,12,0,12">
         <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}" />
     </ScrollViewer>
   </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That looks good, can you not use the ScrollViewer within the ListBox rather than wrapping it in one? Something like `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,12,0,12" />`

Comment: @Richard that doesn't work, which was a little surprising. Once the available space is filled (i.e. with the button pushed to the bottom of the window), the listbox continues to grow vertically, but is clipped within that central area, and no scrollbars appear. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: hmmm very strange, I would expect that to work, but admit I've found a few funnies with ScrollViewer in the past so I'm not surprised it's a bit flakey.

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the height of the grid row containing your `ListBox` to some fixed height to stop it taking up whatever vertical height it likes. I'm away from an IDE to test but you may also need to set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` on the `ListBox` to Auto.

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="400">  
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading" />

   <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}" 
           Margin="0,12,0,12" />

   <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This just fixes the height of the listbox at 200 pixels. I'm trying to let the listbox grow in size vertically until it has pushed the button to the bottom edge of the window, and from then on, display scrollbars in the listbox.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I missed that in your OP, apologies.